# Zalenium - multiple browser interaction

Tags: zalenium

I want to know if I Can open 2-3 browser in zalenium and switch between these browser to automate a flow where I enter data in 1  browser, I need to validate the data in the second browser and vice versa. Both browsers are chrome browsers. Can I use the `driver.manage.window.switch (windowhanle)` function.

Any examples will help.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, each node started will Zalenium will only run one browser. This is done by design, so video and log collection is performed in a clean way.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Appreciate it. I also wanted to check if there are any examples that have the grid started on a EC2 instance? I am able to install and start the image on the EC2 but unable to connect. I am trying to use the <public dns>:4444/wd/hub